# Sort set with specific elements at beginning ascending

Tags: java, sorting, set, comparator

I have a set of objects with a `name` attribute. Some of this objects should be showed at the beginnig of the set in ascending order and the rest should also be sorted in ascending order after the elements at the beginning. The comments at the sets are the content of the sets.

Here are some examples:

Expected output is `("abc", "hello", "a", "c", "f", "test")`

```
Set<Props> props = handler.getProps(); //("test", "abc", "c", "f", "hello", "a")
Set<Props> unnecessaryProps = handler.getUnnecessaryProps(); //("hello", "abc")

Comparator comparator = new Comparator<Props>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Props e1, Props e2) {
        if (e1.equals(e2)) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (unnecessaryProps.contains(e1)) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (unnecessaryProps.contains(e2)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return e1.compare(e2);
        }
    };
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: This comparator looks wrong: if both e1 and e2 are in unnecessaryProps, it should return 0 (or e1.compare(e2)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TreeSet` has a constructor with a comparator parameter. You can use it to create sorted sets. Then you can add two sorted sets to a `LinkedHashSet` to keep the right order.

- Create a set of `name` fields (`unlist`) to filter `props` by the elements in the `unnecessaryProps`
- Create a comparator `cmp` that compares `Props` by `name` field:
  `Comparator.comparing(Props::getName)`
- Create two `TreeSet`s using this comparator in the constructor:
  `new TreeSet<>(cmp)`
- Now you have two sorted sets by name: `[a, c, f, test]` and `[abc, hello]`
- Add the two sets in a `LinkedHashSet` in the right order.

---

```
Set<String> unlist = unnecessaryProps.stream().map(Props::getName).collect(Collectors.toSet());

Set<Props> output = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Comparator<Props> cmp = Comparator.comparing(Props::getName);

Set<Props> propstr = new TreeSet<>(cmp);
propstr.addAll(props.stream().filter(p -> !unlist.contains(p.getName())).collect(Collectors.toSet()));

Set<Props> unstr = new TreeSet<>(cmp);
unstr.addAll(unnecessaryProps);

output.addAll(unstr);
output.addAll(propstr);

System.out.println(output);
```

Output:

```
[abc, hello, a, c, f, test]
```

I assume the `Props` class has a `toString()` method to print the `name` values:

```
public class Props {
    // ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```